# Chrome extension: sendResponse vs chrome.tabs.sendMessage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm a bit confused by the usage of `sendResponse` (as in `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`) and `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`.

What I'm trying to do is that I want to send a message from the content script to the background, and the background will respond with some appropriate message. The code that I have is as follows.

In content script:

```
var currentHost = window.location.host;
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: 'getUsageTime', host: currentHost }, function (res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

In background:

```
function onMessage (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.type === 'getUsageTime') {
    console.log('Getting the usage time for ' + message.host);
    sendResponse({ usageTime: usageTime });
    return true;
  }
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(onMessage);
```

What this does is that the content script will send a message to request the usage time of that particular host. According to my current understanding of what `sendResponse` does, the code above (in particular, the line `console.log(res)`) should be able to log the response message. However, this is not as expected and that line of code does nothing (and probably isn't even reached).

Moreover, if I try to send a message in the background by `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` and supplying the appropriate tab id, that works (as expected) but it's too troublesome to fire another `sendMessage` in the background this way.

What exactly is happening here? What are the differences between `sendResponse` and `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`? Why is my code not working?

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: At the first glance, your code should work. Where does `usageTime` come from? Have you simplified the code here?

Comment: `usageTime` is basically a string used to identify the type of message I'm sending. Oh, you have reminded me that I'm placing `sendResponse` inside another `chrome.storage.local.get` callback. If I move it out of that callback, it would work. But why is this so?

Comment: Aha. Then, let me find the canonical question..

Comment: Exactly the solution I'm looking for. Thank you. (Actually I browsed through that page several times but I didn't realise that it is the same problem I'm facing...)